# Swagger isn't smart enough to handle anonymous types (such as maps)

Tags: java, swagger, enunciate, swagger-ui

I'm using [enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) to generate [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/) documentation for a REST API. One of my legacy beans contains a Map, and Swagger complains about this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enunciate-plugin:1.27:docs (default) @ foo-api ---
[INFO] initializing enunciate.
[INFO] invoking enunciate:generate step...
[WARNING] Validation result has errors.
/.../rest/BarBean.java:170: [swagger] Swagger isn't smart enough to handle anonymous types (such as maps).
   public HashMap<String, BazBean> getBazBeans() {
```

Are there any annotations I can drop into the bean class so that Swagger can handle this?

Barring that, is there a way to tell Swagger to simply ignore the field or the whole class? I know that Swagger ignores classes without the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, but `BazBean` is tragically used in another endpoint that accepts XML.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to get around the problem:

1. Exclude the legacy class `BarBean` from your enunciate maven configuration
2. Add a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to the `BarBean#getBazBeans()` method

I will describe the second solution in more detail, because the first is well known. The return type of `getBazBeans()` is an anonymous type, meaning that it's not declared in your project. You can change this with an `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter`, connecting it to the `getBazBeans()` methods return type via the `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation

```
import import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
public class BarBean {

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( BazBeansAdapter.class )
  Map<String, BazBean> getBazBeans() { /* ... */ }

}

public class BazBeansAdapter extends XmlAdapter<BazBeansContainer, Map<String, BayBean>> {

  /*
  Your implementation of serialization and deserialization. 
  Usually creating and reading the container object. 
  */

}


public class BazBeansContainer {

  private Map<String, BayBean> beans;    

  /* Getter, Setter, etc. */

}
```

Comment: Why BazBeansContainer still has unmappable class Map<String, BayBean>?